# Web reviews and accessing data via independant android app

Tags: android, database, web, database-connection

Still new to android and will be for some time. I could use a little help getting started. Here is what I am trying to do, two parts.

Part one - I would like to have a website that would give users a chance to enter information about various places to eat or things to do in the area. All of that information would be stored on an online data base as more and more people enter reviews and ideas.

Part two - Next, I would like to develop an android app that would directly pull data from that very same online database and display it in the app with out going to the website.

My question(s)
Can an android app access any online database used to store such content that is continually updated by users?

I am in the process of designing my website and want to ensure the functionality of the website will allow my android app to actively open a data connection and refresh the data that is continuously updated. Can anyone point in the right direction? I pretty much don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

> Can an android app access any online database used to store such content that is continually updated by users?

Yes.

You need a server of some sort for that. You could use pretty much anything you decide, php with mysql is probably a good choice for you, it usually is, it's cheap, fast, flexible, easy to learn, widely known and supported.

If people need to interact with your database while they're surfing the web, that would be very easy to do in PHP. Then to an android app to access it, it's relatively straight forward, just google or search here on SO for the many, many questions on showing information in android from a mysql database running php.

You're better off exploring the above with as much vigour as you can, then ask as specific questions as you can. Split it up, ask questions that solve precisely one (small) problem.